# Capture mic input from an outgoing call and streaming the audio to an api

Tags: android, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am trying to create an app that can capture and stream mic input to a speech to text from an outgoing call on android.

I already have a code for capturing an audio stream to an api. All I need now is a code for capturing a call audio at the same time as streaming it to the api.

```
    package com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.MicrophoneHelper;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.MicrophoneInputStream;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.StreamPlayer;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.utils.ContentType;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.camera.CameraHelper;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.camera.GalleryHelper;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.LanguageTranslator;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.model.TranslateOptions;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.model.TranslationResult;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.util.Language;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.security.IamOptions;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.SpeechToText;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.RecognizeOptions;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeechRecognitionResults;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.websocket.BaseRecognizeCallback;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.TextToSpeech;
    import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.model.SynthesizeOptions;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    /*
     * Copyright 2017 IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
     * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on
     * an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
     * specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
     */




    public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
        private final String TAG = "MainMenu";

        private EditText input;
        private ImageButton mic;
        private Button translate;
        private ImageButton play;
        private TextView translatedText;
        private ImageView loadedImage;

        private SpeechToText speechService;
        private TextToSpeech textService;
        private LanguageTranslator translationService;
        private String selectedTargetLanguage = Language.SPANISH;

        private StreamPlayer player = new StreamPlayer();

        private CameraHelper cameraHelper;
        private GalleryHelper galleryHelper;
        private MicrophoneHelper microphoneHelper;

        private MicrophoneInputStream capture;
        private boolean listening = false;

        /**
         * On create.
         *
         * @param savedInstanceState the saved instance state
         */
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
            BottomNavigationView bottomNav= findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
            bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new DialFragment()).commit();

            microphoneHelper = new MicrophoneHelper(this);

            speechService = initSpeechToTextService();



            input = findViewById(R.id.input);
            mic = findViewById(R.id.mic);







            mic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!listening) {
                        // Update the icon background
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mic.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            }
                        });
                        capture = microphoneHelper.getInputStream(true);
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    speechService.recognizeUsingWebSocket(getRecognizeOptions(capture),
                                            new MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate());
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    showError(e);
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();

                        listening = true;
                    } else {
                        // Update the icon background
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mic.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                            }
                        });
                        microphoneHelper.closeInputStream();
                        listening = false;
                    }
                }
            });


        }




        private void showError(final Exception e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // Update the icon background
                    mic.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                }
            });
        }

        private void showMicText(final String text) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    input.setText(text);
                }
            });
        }

        private void enableMicButton() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mic.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }

        private SpeechToText initSpeechToTextService() {
            IamOptions options = new IamOptions.Builder()
                    .apiKey(getString(R.string.speech_text_iam_apikey))
                    .build();
            SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText(options);
            service.setEndPoint(getString(R.string.speech_text_url));
            return service;

        }



        private RecognizeOptions getRecognizeOptions(InputStream captureStream) {
            return new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                    .audio(captureStream)

                    .contentType(ContentType.OPUS.toString())
                    .model("en-US_BroadbandModel")
                    .interimResults(true)
                    .inactivityTimeout(2000)
                    .build();
        }

        private abstract class EmptyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            // assumes text is initially empty
            private boolean isEmpty = true;

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() == 0) {
                    isEmpty = true;
                    onEmpty(true);
                } else if (isEmpty) {
                    isEmpty = false;
                    onEmpty(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

            public abstract void onEmpty(boolean empty);
        }

        private class MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate extends BaseRecognizeCallback {
            @Override
            public void onTranscription(SpeechRecognitionResults speechResults) {
                System.out.println(speechResults);
                if (speechResults.getResults() != null && !speechResults.getResults().isEmpty()) {
                    String text = speechResults.getResults().get(0).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript();
                    showMicText(text);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                try {
                    // This is critical to avoid hangs
                    // (see https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/issues/59)
                    capture.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                showError(e);
                enableMicButton();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected() {
                enableMicButton();
            }
        }






        /**
         * On request permissions result.
         *
         * @param requestCode the request code
         * @param permissions the permissions
         * @param grantResults the grant results
         */
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               String[] permissions,
                                               int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case CameraHelper.REQUEST_PERMISSION: {
                    // permission granted
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        cameraHelper.dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    }
                }
                case MicrophoneHelper.REQUEST_PERMISSION: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission to record audio denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * On activity result.
         *
         * @param requestCode the request code
         * @param resultCode the result code
         * @param data the data
         */
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == CameraHelper.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                loadedImage.setImageBitmap(cameraHelper.getBitmap(resultCode));
            }

            if (requestCode == GalleryHelper.PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                loadedImage.setImageBitmap(galleryHelper.getBitmap(resultCode, data));
            }
        }


        private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener= new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment=null;
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_dialer:
                        selectedFragment=new DialFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_contacts:
                        selectedFragment=new ContactsFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_transcripts:
                        selectedFragment=new TranscriptsFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        selectedFragment=new SettingsFragment();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
```

I expect to be able to simultaneously throw audio input from the microphone to IBM Watson Speech to Text and make a call at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution. . . .
created the method for android system calls.

```
private void makePhoneCall(){
        String number=input.getText().toString();
        if (number.trim().length()>0)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL);
            }
            else{
                String dial="tel:"+number;
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

then I placed this method inside the on click listener.

```
 mic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!listening) {
           makePhoneCall();
          // Update the icon background
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              mic.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
          });
          capture = microphoneHelper.getInputStream(true);
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              try {

                speechService.recognizeUsingWebSocket(getRecognizeOptions(capture),
                    new MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate());
              } catch (Exception e) {
                showError(e);
              }
            }
          }).start();

          listening = true;
        } else {
          // Update the icon background
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              mic.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
          });
          microphoneHelper.closeInputStream();
          listening = false;
        }
      }
    });
```

Will post more later to add functionalities such as the speech to text transcription will start later after the call connects and stops after it disconnects.

Comment: Is there is a native android way to capture audio stream without any third party library During the call